# Which is correct use of the apostophe in minutes?

Tags: possessives, apostrophe, attributive-nouns

Minutes walk to the building. 
or 
Minutes' walk to the building.
or
Minute's walk to the building.

As in it is several minutes walk to the building...

Comment: If it takes a minute, *a minute's walk*. If it takes several minutes, "a several minutes' walk". If it takes 5 minutes, "a five-minute walk/a five minutes' walk*

Comment: @Rathony, I'm guessing you speak American English? Just "several minutes' walk" would be more common in the UK

Comment: @ChrisH How about **a** five-minutes' walk?

Comment: @Rathony, no, "five minutes' walk". Any variations with "a" sound old-fashioned: "a mere five minutes' walk", "a walk of five minutes" etc.

Comment: @ChrisH I see your point. Well... Let's see whether others find them old-fashioned.

Comment: Following "a three-course meal", I take "a thirty-minute walk" every day. I may be old fashioned, but I wouldn't contemplate "a thirty-minute**s** walk".

Answer (score 2):

You can use the apostrophe immediately after the **s** of **minutes** but need not add an extra **s**. That would be **incorrect**.

> "Ten minutes' walk" is fine. "Ten minutes's walk" is incorrect.

Because it is a plural, adding another "s" is not correct.

So the answer is:

> several minutes' walk to the building...

[Possessives and apostrophes](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/621/01/) has some good rules and explanations for this.

Answer (score 2):

Standard orthography uses *minutes'* here. To see why, note that in the singular, we say "one minute's walk", not *"one minute walk". So we need the possessive form, which in the plural is *minutes'*.

Comment: "One minute walk" strikes me as impeccable Standard English. Albeit in writing, it is likely to be hyphenated.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: That's different: you're thinking of "a one-minute walk" (note the "a"). For that one, we never pluralize "minute": "a ten-minute walk", not \*"a ten-minutes walk".

Answer (score -1):

There is no difference between 'correct English' in the US or in the UK people.  It is all English.  Variations are colloquial corruptions.  We are describing what kind of walk it is.  That means the word minute functions as an adjective and adjectives never take an 's' and never require an apostrophe.  Who says a twenty dollars bill or a ten pounds note???

Comment: Hello, Jim. I'm happier with 'Just a minute's walk away is ....' than 'Just a minute walk away is ....' And there are plenty of examples to be found on the internet (admittedly not only for the Saxon genitive form I prefer here, but also for the singular-form (_minute_) attributive usage). And 'He is three foot/feet high' are both commonly used.