# Articles with Spatial Prepositions

Tags: grammar, articles, syntactic-analysis, indefinite-articles

Are both sentences correct? with and without the indefinite article (a):

> She lives two minutes' walk from the station
>
> She lives a two minutes' walk from the station

Comment: The difference between them is not about "spatial prepositions"at all. "two-minute walk".

Comment: She lives **a two-minute walk** from the station.

Answer (score 0):

The second sounds wrong to me, because it *sounds* like you're using *a* with a plural. Of course *walk* is actually singular.

> She lives two minutes' walk from the station
>
> She lives **a two-minute walk** from the station

According to [Which is correct use of the apostophe in minutes?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/280155/which-is-correct-use-of-the-apostophe-in-minutes#comment621051_280155) *a two-minutes' walk* is not wrong.

Comment: “A two-minutes’ walk” sounds correct, although in spoken form the listener can’t detect either the hyphen or the placement of the apostrophe. The archetype here is “a minute’s walk” or “an hour’s drive”, where we let the unit of time take possession of the activity it contains. The choice between the possessive time interval and the noun-as-adjective time interval is mostly a matter of convention. Intuitively, the simpler and more clearly visualized intervals are more possessive.

Comment: They are both right. People forget that the determiner **a** can be expressed with a noun as a plural. Like this:  I love **an** egg for breakfast. OR I love egg**s** for breakfast.

Answer (score 0):

It is the one **without** the article that is correct:

*She lives **two minutes' walk** from the station.*

**Discussion**

The phrases in boldface below are called *measure genitives,* or, alternatively, *genitives of measure* ([Longman](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0582237254), p. 296, which where the four examples below come from):

*Perhaps he took my thousand dollars and put me to skep with **two dollars'**
worth of ether.

Their huts were **12 hours'** journey from the nearest main road.

I want **ten years'** supply of whisky.

I held the telephone at **arm's** length and stared at it.*

As is clear already from the first three examples, when a cardinal number precedes the noun in the genitive, we generally don't need another determiner in front.

This doesn't mean, however, that we may *never* put another determiner in front. Consider the following examples from [CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521431468) (p. 470):

*a second [one hour's delay]

the [one dollar's worth of chocolates] he bought*

Arguably, the following are also acceptable: *a second [two hours' delay], the [two dollars' worth of chocolates] he bought.* CGEL says that these examples show that measure genitives are attributive modifiers rather than determiners, because in these examples they actually follow a determiner (immediately or with an intervening adjectival attribute). CGEL further says that

> When they occur in this position, i.e. after a determiner, they are subject to the constraint described in §6.2, so that the indefinite article is dropped: instead of <sup>*</sup>*this [an hour's delay]* we have *this [hour's delay].* In this case the measure genitive (*hour's*) has the status of a nominal, but otherwise measure genitives are full NPs (noun phrases).
>
> Because they are modifiers not determiners, measure genitives do not confer definiteness on the NP. While *a friend's dog,* with Type 1 genitive, is definite ("the dog of a friend"), *an hour's delay* is indefinite ("delay of an hour"). Nor can they occur initially with nouns that require a count interpretation: <sup>*</sup>*We played [an hour's game of squash]*; instead we need the compound adjective construction *We played a [ one-hour game of squash].*

If the last sentence is correct, by the way, it implies that *walk* is used as an **uncountable** noun in your example. This is rather extraordinary, because I certainly can't think of another construction where *walk* is uncount. For example, <sup>*</sup>*I had/did lots of **walk** today* doesn't work. Moreover, among the major dictionaries that explicitly state whether a given sense of a noun is count or uncount ([*Cambridge*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/walk?q=walk_1), [*Collins*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/walk), and [*Macmillan*](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/walk_2)), none of them record an uncount sense for the noun *walk*. Nevertheless, postulating that *walk* is uncount in *two minutes' walk* does have the advantage of making it unsurprising that no determiner is needed in front; after all, count nouns in the singular normally require a determiner, whereas uncount nouns in the singular do not require one as long as they are indefinite. The disadvantage is that *walk* is not the only noun for which we need to postulate this unique uncount sense: we have to do the same with *dollar* and *arm*, for example.

As usual, analyzing grammatical rules that someone wrote down is actually not decisive as far as whether a given construction is acceptable or not.  What we need to do is look at actual patterns of usage among native speakers. So, let's verify that the article is indeed missing in reputable sources such as published books. This is indeed so: see the numerous examples [here](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&ei=VlI2XdjdJYnJ5gKxtpHoAQ&q=%22lives+*+minutes%27+walk%22&oq=%22lives+*+minutes%27+walk%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...12924.13437.0.14169.4.4.0.0.0.0.213.409.1j1j1.3.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.2.196...33i299k1.0.EXtzTEGPIro) and [here](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&ei=9DQ2XfajPMuHgge8kIj4BQ&q=%22after+*+hours%27+delay%22+-%22after+only+*+hours%27+delay%22&oq=%22after+*+hours%27+delay%22+-%22after+only+*+hours%27+delay%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...7426468.7430987.0.7432266.8.8.0.0.0.0.79.583.8.8.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.xAii_7Mo6b0). Here and there we find usage with an article (e.g. [here](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1405&bih=628&tbm=bks&ei=nlM2XbLAEoPf5gLr_7OwCQ&q=%22is+a+two+hours%27+drive%22&oq=%22is+a+two+hours%27+drive%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...14114.14537.0.15095.2.2.0.0.0.0.130.226.1j1.2.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.-9nEltqNPaM)), but that is very rare by comparison.

Comment: I'm very happy with 'She lives a two-minute walk [away] from....' There are plenty of similar examples on the internet. The time involved is a free (within reason) choice, and 'drive' (and perhaps other sensibly chosen nouns) may be used in place of 'walk'. I'd not consider 'walk' a count usage here any more than 'light' in 'a subtle light filtered through the foliage'. It's perhaps best to regard 'a three-hour drive', 'a stone's throw' etc as (quasi–)distance-measures, fixed expressions/idioms with internal countness for those where the time may be adjusted.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ah, but *a two-minute walk* doesn't involve a genitive. So it's either *she lives **a** two-**minute** walk from the station* or  *she lives **ø** two **minutes'** walk from the station*, where *ø* is the 'zero article'. What the OP was asking about was the case with both the indefinite article and a genitive, * *she lives **a** two **minutes'** walk from the station*, and that one doesn't work.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth As far as *a subtle light,* there are important differences between that usage and e.g. *a two-hour walk*, arguably important enough to insist that *light* is still uncount there. First, with *light*, note that you can omit the article if you want [(an example)](https://books.google.com/books?id=7CmdDgAAQBAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PT58&dq=%22subtle%20light%20filtered%20%22&pg=PT58#v=onepage&q=%22subtle%20light%20filtered%20%22&f=false), but you cannot omit the article in *She went for a two-hour walk*.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Second, the effect of the *a* with NPs of the form adjective+uncount noun is 'to individuate a subamount' of the noun ('light'), 'but this individuation does not yield an entity conceptualised as belonging to a class of entities of the same kind' (CGEL, p. 339). For example, this is not acceptable: * *There was a subtle light coming through the north window and **another** coming through the east window*. But if you replace *light* by the countable noun *sound*, it becomes acceptable.

Comment: _A nine days' wonder_ is one acceptable variant of the idiom [[CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-a-nine-days-wonder)].

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Interesting! But as far as *walk*, *journey*, etc., to your ear, do the versions with both an indefinite article and the genitive sound natural? These: *she lives **a** two **minutes'** walk away*; *that is **a** three **days'** yourney from here.*

Comment: More so than the singular-form attributive with some (eg a nine days' wonder, a three days' journey).  With 'childrens clothing departments', 'writers guilds',  and certainly 'working mens clubs' becoming acceptable, perhaps _**these**_ non-possessive strings will similarly just drop the apostrophe. // Exodus 8:27 [[BibleHub](https://biblehub.com/exodus/8-27.htm)] has some interesting alternatives!

Comment: You say that *arm* and *dollar* would have to have uncountable senses, but this isn't quite right. These nouns are part of the measure phrase, not the 'uncountable' noun that the measure phrase modifies.

Comment: I want ten years' supply of whisky. is the same as: I want a ten-year supply of whisky. People forget that one can often use the determiner a + noun OR a plural noun. So: It's **a ten-minute walk** OR It's **ten minutes' walk**. And I bet my bottom dollar that CGEL does not explain that logic. I don't much like saying count noun because it implies the noun can count.

Comment: You can walk the walk and talk the talk.  And there's the walk of shame.